# It is possible to deploy only one file using deploy command?

Tags: javascript, css, less, static-content-deploy, production-mode

In production mode when I change the design of some particular block or page then I am only working on one or two files like js and CSS.

To apply that one change I need to deploy the whole theme.

Can we deploy one file or deploy CSS or js content particularly?

just like when I change some design in the frontend section and delete the static file in theme and deploy it only for that theme and area

`rm -rf Local/argento-stripes-custom/fr_FR/Magento_Checkout/*`

`php bin/magento s:s:d -f en_US fr_FR -a frontend -t Local/argento-stripes-custom`

[image: deploy fronend theme only]

it only deploy require theme for frontend only.

So, it is possible to deploy Module changes only like

`php bin/magento s:s:d -f en_US fr_FR -a frontend -t Local/argento-stripes-custom/Magento_Checkout/`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no it's not - because of theme inheritance

However have you considered building the theme in a magento mirror folder (build folder) outside of web root using the same db credentials and then rsync the mirror build to web root.

Rsync options can be used to overwrite or delete the difference. Gives you a bit more protection if a less error halts the process in your build folder. That's the basis for most deployment processes I've seen.

Comment: if it will possible to deploy one module with its dependency then it reduces one more con of the monolithic architecture of Magento :D